# Full disk encryption: remotely enter password (Veracrypt or other solutions)

Tags: encryption, passwords, networking, disk-encryption, veracrypt

my computer's OS drive is fully encrypted with Veracrypt's system encryption: https://veracrypt.eu/en/System%20Encryption.html

Is there a way to remotely enter the password in the [pre-boot authentication screen](https://www.wintips.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/image-89.png)? Like sending it via LAN or something?

I was thinking about using a VPN to remote myself *into* another device in my LAN (eg. a raspberry pi), but then what? AFAIK Veracrypt doesn't have an SSH interface or anything...

I *think* that an IPKVM device could be a solution, but those usually cost a lot ([or require DIY work](https://pikvm.org/)).

---

If it's not possible **at all** with Veracrypt, is there some other software alternative for full disk encryption that allows a remote unlock?

Comment: Do you mean that you're turning on this computer remotely? Are you on Windows/Linux?

Comment: Yes i mean turning on the PC and entering veracrypt's full disk encryption password. I'm running windows but it doesn't make a difference as i'm talking about veracrypt's **pre-boot** authentication

Comment: Have you since solved this issue or have any other feedback?

Comment: @PadraigD yes, see my own answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this is how i solved it:

- i made an IP-KVM via [Tinypilot](https://github.com/tiny-pilot/tinypilot) and a RaspberryPI4
- i set up a VPN to get into my LAN remotely
- i can now connect to the VPN and just open https://raspberrypi in a browser to access Tinypilot and see my desktop pc screen to type the password via the web browser

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to remotely enter the password in the pre-boot authentication screen? Like sending it via LAN or something?

The only feasible solutions I can think of are IP KVM or else transfer the disk to a virtual environment (which is likely a security risk). IP KVM is a keyboard/video/mouse interface over IP, so it isn't just "like sending it via LAN", it is *literally* that.

Maybe a password isn't your best choice here? Consider [using Veracrypt with a Yubikey](https://docs.yubikey.wiki/tutorials/veracrypt) or [keyfile](https://veracrypt.eu/en/Keyfiles%20in%20VeraCrypt.html) (including other [security tokens and smart cards](https://veracrypt.eu/en/Keyfiles%20in%20VeraCrypt.html#SmartCard)), assuming you have some way of specifying or unlocking them over a network connection.

Comment: what do you mean by virtual environment?

Comment: also, a physical token wouldn't be a solution because it would require physical insertion in the computer (AFAIK). so then yes, i could be able to start and unlock the pc, but so would anyone with physical access or anyone in the LAN (i'd start the pc with WOL, i forgot to mention), because i'd have to leave the yubikey inserted in the computer.

Comment: If you move the content to a virtual disk and open it in a virtual machine, you can connect to it remotely as it boots. Yubikey can be used as a one-time password, meaning you're not at as much risk sending the password across a network. You may also be able to connect a remote USB device through a VM.

Comment: ok but what do you mean by moving **the content**? the entire OS in a virtual machine? at that point, apart from performance considerations (i don't have an actual server, just a desktop pc i'm using as a server), i wouldn't even need the physical token i think, right? i would just remote into my LAN (onto a raspberry), then connect to the VM (vmware?) over the LAN, and just work from there

Comment: You should probably reevaluate the whole setup from first principles: what you're trying to protect, from what angles, and to what degree. Rather than dumping your encrypted drive to a file so it can be hosted in a VM, you might want to boot from a smart token (leave it in the USB slot) and then additionally encrypt your user content after booting up.

Comment: yes i'm open to reevaluating everything, no problem. since physical access is a concern (as i'm often far away from the machine), a physical token inserted in the computer would not be enough to stop someone from accessing the device. is this correct, or am i missing something? i never used a yubikey or similar

Comment: You are correct. That's why I'm suggesting a second level of encryption that requires you to log in and decrypt after booting. On Linux, you could do this with [eCryptfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs) (this even lets you encrypt your home directory and can automatically decrypt upon password-based login). Surely other OSes have similar options.

Comment: is ecryptfs what ubuntu uses if you check the "encrypt home directory" during its install procedure?

Comment: That is correct. Ubuntu's [EncryptedHome](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome) docs aren't great, so maybe look at [How to Encrypt Your Home Folder After Installing Ubuntu](https://www.howtogeek.com/116032/how-to-encrypt-your-home-folder-after-installing-ubuntu/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a real solution for remote reboot is possible with
Veracrypt pre-boot authentication.

This is possible using Bitlocker with various solutions.
The simplest would be, if you know that you're going to connect remotely,
to suspend once the protection through the "Manage Bitlocker" utility.
For more details see the article
[Working remotely: restarting your Windows computer](https://kb.rice.edu/page.php?id=98580).

If you are in a domain environment and have an available
always-on Windows Server, you could
[Manage encrypted PCs remotely using BitLocker Network Unlock](https://4sysops.com/archives/manage-encrypted-pcs-remotely-using-bitlocker-network-unlock/).

It might be simpler to avoid the entire problem and unencrypt the
system partition, to enable normal boot, and instead partition
your data off in a separate partition which is encrypted by either
Bitlocker or Veracrypt.

Comment: 1-manually suspending bitlocker whenever i have to restart the device, would be impractical and at times impossible - what about reboots after a power outage?

Comment: 2-unfortunately i'm not in a domain and i'm not even running windows server, just windows desktop, but i am using veracrypt because i foresee switching to linux in the future, so veracrypt would be an agnostic solution

Comment: 2.1- is bitlocker the only valid alternative to veracrypt? i believe (and hope) that there's some other alternative..

Comment: 3- yes, it might be simpler to not encrypt the whole drive, but it would be insecure. what if the OS or a program access a private file, located in the encrypted partition, and for any reason caches it in the OS (non encrypted) drive? accessing the OS drive in that state (eg. by physically removing the disk and reading it on another computer) would give access to unencrypted but sensitive files

Comment: Bitlocker is built-into Windows, but Veracrypt is much more versatile, so might be the better choice. If you worry about unencrypting the Windows partition, you could relocate to the Veracrypt disk the folders most apt to contain unintended personal data, such as the user's Documents folder. With Windows unencrypted, the installation will be much more resilient against disk bad spots.

Comment: sure but there's always the problem that an app, any app, for any reason, could copy/move (even temporarily) files from the veracrypt encrypted folder, to a non encrypted folder. that would be a problem